# Pandas: Drop Column If Submatrix Has Enough Nulls

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing some machine learning on Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques#description) and am given a train CSV and a test CSV.

I want to drop columns in my data where at least 30% of values are null.  If I were just doing this for my training set, I would do this:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
train_len = len(train_df)
test_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
threshold = int(0.7 * train_len)
train_df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=threshold, inplace=True)
```

This works.  However, I want to drop these columns in my test set as well.  So specifically, I'd like to find the columns in my training set that have 30% or more null values and drop them from train and test sets.

I was thinking of combining my DataFrames like this:

```
combined_df = pd.concat([train_df, test_df], axis=0)
```

If `combined_df[:train_len, :]` has more than 30% nulls, drop that column from `combined_df`.

How would I do this?  To be clear, I don't want to loop through train, find columns with more than 30% nulls, drop from train, then drop from test.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
train_df.columns[train_df.isnull().sum()/len(train_df)>0.3]
Out[1391]: Index(['B'], dtype='object')

combined_df.loc[:,train_df.isnull().sum()/len(df)>0.3]
Out[1394]: 
     B
0  2.0
1  NaN
2  4.0
3  NaN
```

Data input

```
     A    B
0  1.0  2.0
1  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  4.0
3  4.0  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  However, I don't just want to drop it for `df`.  I want to combined `train_df` and `test_df` and drop columns of `combined_df` based on the ones in `train_df` that are missing at least 30% of their values

Comment: @bclayman change the df to train_df, and collect the column need to drop .I am just using df as a sample data set

Answer (score 1):

After you drop the columns in `test_df`, just use the remaining column names to select columns in `test_df`.

```
train_df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=threshold, inplace=True)
test_df = test_df[train_df.columns]
```